# Why does Ask Different receive so much spam posts?

Tags: discussion, spam

I have been fairly active over the past three weeks. I have a tab with newest questions open all the time.

I couldn't help but notice the amount of spam that gets posted on the site. Just curious for various reasons, why does this happen? Isn't there an automated way to stop it? The pattern of the posts appear consistent. Why aren't the spammers discouraged after seeing constant flagging and deletions within moments? Could it possibly be a bot posting the spam.

Comment: Don‘t have time for an answer, just for two related links: https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1911/how-to-handle-blatant-off-topic-spam, https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2929/request-for-spam-information